# Is it possible to use a C++ library from a kotlin multiplatform mobile app?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-multiplatform-mobile

I have a C++ library that I need to use from android and iOS, so my idea is to create a multiplatform module that would wrap the library to use it from both implementations.

In other hand, I've seen a sample where C code is used by kotlin native:
https://theprogrammershangout.com/resources/kotlin/native/creating-c-bindings.md/

Also this one from kotlin documentation:
https://kotlinlang.org/docs/native-c-interop.html

Would that be possible to make that interoperability work with jvm and iOS?

Comment: Hey! I'm working on the same problem. Have you found any solution for this by chance? Maybe you have a "Hello world" template available to share? :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot directly interop with C++ from Kotlin/Native (using cinterop). Your C++ library would need to expose an `extern C` version of itself, or you'd need to create a C compatible bridge to your C++ library, and let cinterop look at that.

It might be more natural to wrap that with an Objective-C interface rather than a C one, but that will obviously depend on what the library does and your comfort level with C vs Objective-C.

Comment: The Obective-C wrapper would only be for iOS, correct? Is another wrapper necessary for Android? Or do you use the C++ library directly in Kotlin Android?

Comment: In reading a bit more, it looks like you have to create a JNI wrapper for Android to access C++.

Comment: How can we create a compatible bridge with extern c. Can you put one complete example for KMM native project.